# How can I debug browserify-ied files in IDEA?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, browserify

I am using browserify to combine all my js files.

How do I configure Intellij IDEA's javascript debugging so that it can find my files?

If I don't use browserify, I can debug the files using IDEA.
I am using gulp-browserify and am setting up debug to true.

Thanks